# Python how to find unique entries and get the minimum values from a matching array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, `indices`:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  2],
       [95, 71, 95]])
```

I have another array of the same length called `distances`:

```
array([  0.98713981,   1.04705992,   1.42340327, 74.0139111 ,
    74.4285216 ,  74.84623217])
```

All of the rows in `indices` have a match in the `distances` array. The problem is, there are duplicates in the `indices` array, and they have different values in the corresponding `distances` array. I would like to get the minimum distance for all triplets of indices, and discard the others. Therefore, with the inputs above, I want the output:

```
indicesOUT = 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  2],
       [95, 71, 95]])

distancesOUT=
array([  0.98713981,  1.42340327,  74.84623217])
```

My current strategy is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

indicesOUT = []
distancesOUT = []

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        for k in range(6):
            if len([s for s in indicesOUT if [i,j,k] == s]) == 0:
                current = np.array([i, j, k])
                ind = np.where((indices == current).all(-1) == True)[0]
                currentDistances = distances[ind]
                dist = np.amin(distances)
                indicesOUT.append([i, j, k])
                distancesOUT.append(dist)
```

The problem is, the actual arrays have about 4 million elements each, so this approach is way too slow. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a grouping operation, and NumPy is not well-optimized for it. Fortunately, the Pandas package has some very fast tools that can be adapted to this exact problem.
With your data above, we can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

def drop_duplicates(indices, distances):
    data = pd.Series(distances)
    grouped = data.groupby(list(indices.T)).min().reset_index()
    return grouped.values[:, :3], grouped.values[:, 3]
```

And the output for your data is

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  2.,   0.,   2.],
       [ 95.,  71.,  95.]]),
array([  0.98713981,   1.42340327,  74.84623217])
```

My benchmark shows that for 4,000,000 elements, this should run in about a second:

```
indices = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(4000000, 3))
distances = np.random.random(4000000)
%timeit drop_duplicates(indices, distances)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop
```

As written above, the input order of the indices will not necessarily be preserved; keeping the original order would require a bit more thought.